# How to add custom menu command to VSIX Error Context Menu

Tags: visual-studio-2022, vsix

I looked at the [MS docs on the VS menu list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsmenus?view=visualstudiosdk-2022), and I can't find which menu ID to use.  What I want to do is write a VSIX extension that gives me a menu pick when I right click on an Error message, and it will be able to obtain the contents of the selected error message.

Does anyone know if there is a way to customize that contextual menu?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pick a menu command like "Previous Error" from the context menu, search the various .vsct files under "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Inc", and you should get a hit in the ShellCmdDef.vsct file.

```
  <Button Condition="!Defined(VSE)" guid="CLSID_VsTaskListPackage" id="cmdidErrorListPrevError" priority="0x0000" type="Button">
    <CommandFlag>AllowClientRole</CommandFlag>
    <CommandFlag>DefaultDisabled</CommandFlag>
    <CommandFlag>CommandWellOnly</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>P&amp;revious Error</ButtonText>
      <CommandName>Previous Error</CommandName>
    </Strings>
  </Button>
```

Now you know the ID of the command (cmdidErrorListPrevError), so you can search for that, to find where/how it's placed.

You should get a hit in the ShellCmdPlace.vsct:

```
  <CommandPlacement guid="CLSID_VsTaskListPackage" id="cmdidErrorListPrevError" priority="0x0200">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_ERRORLIST_NEXTPREV_ERR"/>
  </CommandPlacement>
```

Now search on that ID to find the menu that groupID is parented to, which will also take us to ShellCmdPlace.vsct and you can identify the actual context menu:

```
  <Group guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_ERRORLIST_NEXTPREV_ERR" priority="0x0400">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ERRORLIST"/>
  </Group>
```

So now, you should define your own custom menu group parented off the same, with your commands parented to your custom menu group.

Caveat: This doesn't always work as there are a LOT of commands and menus that are not defined in the files included in the VSSDK. But for standard stuff like this, the technique "usually" works :-).

Sincerely,

Comment: Ed, that is a seriously deviously brilliant approach!  Thank you for walking us through the thought process, I bet that will help a LOT of people.  Next is to figure out how to obtain the selected error message, maybe if possible I could call the Copy command to place it in the clipboard and paste from there...

Comment: Weird, it's still placing it in the main View menu.  Here's that section of my VSCT file:

    <Buttons>
      <Button guid="guidFirstExtensionPackageCmdSet" id="MyToolWindowCommandId" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ERRORLIST"/>
        <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic1" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>MyToolWindow</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
    </Buttons>